# How to get user input using FormPage

Tags: functions, syntax, wolfram-cloud, cloud-deploy

I am designing a user interface for a word-ladder game using CloudDeploy, CloudExpression and FormPage and I am having trouble with receiving the user input from the form. What I basically need is a function that will give me access to user's input so that I can display it dynamically. This is what I have done so far:

```
listw = CreateCloudExpression[{"a"}]
 CloudDeploy[
   FormPage[{"input", "Enter your word:"} -> "String", 
    RandomChoice[strNeighb[#input] &]; 
      Function[AppendTo[listw, #input]]; (*strNeighb is a function that shows the neighbour words*)
```

Comment: I have tried very hard to "dynamically display input," though in the slightly different context of an [editable multipage `FormFunction`](http://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/766072). The Wolfram Community post to which I just linked is the best I could do with Mathematica version 10. Perhaps you'll be lucky and it will be possible to get what you want with version 11, which is now the only version that you should seriously consider working with. I'm looking forward to an update to your post that tells about what you found possible.

Comment: The problem with your example is that you're creating one `CloudExpression` for a page that will be potentially accessed by many users. I suggest you look into the new `AskFunction` documentation.

Comment: It may very well be correct that as @Carlo suggests you should be using `AskFunction` instead of `FormPage`. But, my guess is that to make progress on that issue you will first need to include working code in your question. Try a basic example from the documentation. Show a screenshot of your output and explain how your desired output is different.